# Can Battle Master's maneuvering attack choose to move the Battle Master (self) who is using the maneuver?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, fighter, combat-maneuver

Taken from the Player's Handbook (p. 74)

> **Maneuvering Attack.** When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can expend one superiority die to maneuver one of your comrades into a more advantageous position. You add the superiority die to the attack’s damage roll, and you choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you. That creature can use its reaction to move up to half its speed without provoking opportunity attacks from the target of your attack.

Can the "friendly creature who can see or hear you" be the Battle Master who is spending the superiority die / making the attack?

This is how this type of phrasing is applied to spells,  and a reaction can occur on your turn or someone else's, so the way the maneuver is worded makes this a viable idea in my mind.

However, is hitting with an attack, then leaving without taking an opp. attack, and being able to move 45 feet overpowered?

The answer to the question makes or breaks the usefulness of this maneuver.

What if the Battle Master were the only character in the party? (solo adventurer)

Comment: On the question about whether it would be overpowered: It's nothing you can't also do if someone cast "Haste" on you. Granted, casting haste has a higher cost, but it also lasts a minute and has further advantages (double movement  instead of just 50% increase, extra action, AC bonus, etc).

Answer (score 11):

No, you are not "one of your comrades"

Answer (score 0):

> ### Targeting Yourself
>
> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.
> — PHB pg.204

A friendly creature that can see or hear you includes yourself, because it does not *specifically* exclude you.

Comment: Do you have any commentary on why this passage on *spell* targeting is applicable to the battle master feature under discussion, esp. considering its self-contained language on targeting?

Comment: It is the only thing that talks about targeting ever, so it's the only thing we can look at. It would be pretty weird to not use the existing targeting system for the Superiority Die without introducing a specific ruling.